# Remover espaço do titulo em AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho o seguinte Dialog na minha aplicação

[image: Um campo de senha não preenchido com um botão de cancelar e um de aceitar embaixo, tudo isso dentro de um retângulo branco. O fundo da tela é preto e, abaixo do retângulo branco, a frase "A Globo censurou". Abaixo da frase, um teclado numérico está sendo exibido.]

Como podem ver, nele não vou utilizar Titulo (`nomequalquer.setTitle("blabla")`) nem Mensagem. Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para que esse espaço em branco onde ficaria o título de mais ou menos uns 50dp não exista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas adicione antes antes do `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.seulayout)` e logo depois de instanciar seu dialog, a seguinte linha: `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado.